# Load locals from File in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have a file called `first.tfpl` containing the following content:

```
[
{
      name = "Test"
      grants = [
        {
          grant      = ["ADMIN"]
          principals = ${jsonencode(admins)}
        }
}
]
```

In my locals.tf I read it as a template file:

```
locals {
  admins   = ["a","b","c"]
}

locals {
  test = templatefile("first.tfpl", { admins = local.admins })
}
```

Now, I want to combine the list in test with an existing list such as the following:

```
locals {
  mylist= concat(["1","2"], local.test)
}
```

Here I get the error that a list was expected, not a string. Which decoder do I have to use? It seems like local.test is treated as a string.

Comment: Well, it seems you are creating a map with `local.test`. Do you want all the values concatenate all the values or only `principals`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [template](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile) function only returns a string interpolation of the template file with the placeholders filled in. So `local.test` is a string which is why you get the error. Terraform doesnt provide an hcl decoder so if you really want to go down this route then i would suggest writting your template file in yaml or json and then use the decoder to convert the string back to an hcl object.

**first.tfpl**

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Test",
    "grants": [
      {
        "grant": ["ADMIN"],
        "principals": ${jsonencode(admins)}
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**main.tf**

```
locals {
  admins = ["a", "b", "c"]
  test   = jsondecode(templatefile("first.tfpl", { admins = local.admins }))
  mylist = concat(["1", "2"], local.test[0]["grants"][0]["principals"])
}

output "mylist" {
  value = local.mylist
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

mylist = [
  "1",
  "2",
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
]
```

Comment: Although in this example it doesn't really make any sense since you know the values already since you pass them to the template. If I have missed what your trying to achieve please feel free to add a comment.